# Yii2 - Getting unknown property: yii\console\Request::userAgent and Class db does not exist

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I have a problem with Yii2 framework version **2.0.42.1**, with a yii2 advanced app template project.

When I run the yii php script: `php  yii`.

It returns me the following error:

```
Exception 'yii\base\UnknownPropertyException' with message 'Getting unknown property: yii\console\Request::userAgent'

in /usr/src/app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Component.php:155

Stack trace:
#0 /usr/src/app/common/components/VerificationNavigateur.php(23): yii\base\Component->__get('userAgent')
#1 /usr/src/app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/BaseObject.php(109): common\components\VerificationNavigateur->init()
#2 /usr/src/app/common/components/AppBootstrap.php(20): yii\base\BaseObject->__construct()
#3 /usr/src/app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Application.php(333): common\components\AppBootstrap->bootstrap(Object(yii\console\Application))
#4 /usr/src/app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Application.php(279): yii\base\Application->bootstrap()
#5 /usr/src/app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/console/Application.php(125): yii\base\Application->init()
#6 /usr/src/app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/BaseObject.php(109): yii\console\Application->init()
#7 /usr/src/app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Application.php(212): yii\base\BaseObject->__construct(Array)
#8 /usr/src/app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/console/Application.php(90): yii\base\Application->__construct(Array)
#9 /usr/src/app/yii(22): yii\console\Application->__construct(Array)
```

Everything was fine until I ran `composer install`.

Even If I try to downgrade the framework `composer require yiisoft/yii2:2.0.41`, that doesn't change anything.

When I try to run the php script from the vendor folder everything is fine `php vendor/bin/yii`

But when I try to run migrations `php vendor/bin/yii migrate`, this error occurs :

```
Yii Migration Tool (based on Yii v2.0.42.1)

Exception 'yii\di\NotInstantiableException' with message 'Failed to instantiate component or class "db".'

in /usr/src/app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/di/Container.php:510

Caused by: Exception 'ReflectionException' with message 'Class db does not exist'

in /usr/src/app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/di/Container.php:508

Stack trace:
#0 /usr/src/app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/di/Container.php(508): ReflectionClass->__construct('db')
#1 /usr/src/app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/di/Container.php(386): yii\di\Container->getDependencies('db')
#2 /usr/src/app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/di/Container.php(171): yii\di\Container->build('db', Array, Array)
#3 /usr/src/app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/di/Instance.php(176): yii\di\Container->get('db')
#4 /usr/src/app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/di/Instance.php(145): yii\di\Instance->get(NULL)
#5 /usr/src/app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/console/controllers/MigrateController.php(183): yii\di\Instance::ensure(Object(yii\di\Instance), 'yii\\db\\Connecti...')
#6 /usr/src/app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Controller.php(179): yii\console\controllers\MigrateController->beforeAction(Object(yii\base\InlineAction))
#7 /usr/src/app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/console/Controller.php(184): yii\base\Controller->runAction('up', Array)
#8 /usr/src/app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Module.php(534): yii\console\Controller->runAction('up', Array)
#9 /usr/src/app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/console/Application.php(181): yii\base\Module->runAction('migrate/up', Array)
#10 /usr/src/app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/console/Application.php(148): yii\console\Application->runAction('migrate/up', Array)
#11 /usr/src/app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Application.php(392): yii\console\Application->handleRequest(Object(yii\console\Request))
#12 /usr/src/app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/yii(37): yii\base\Application->run()
#13 {main}
```

My database configuration connection file didn't change, common/config/main-local.php:

```
<?php
return [
    'components' => [
        'db' => [
            'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
            'dsn' => 'pgsql:host=172.21.0.3;dbname=dev',
            'username' => 'dev',
            'password' => 'dev',
            'charset' => 'utf8',
        ],
       ...
```

> PHP version: 7.4

> Linux distribution: Ubuntu 20.04

And the Yii2 forum is down for maintenance for a while now.

Comment: add your complete `common/config/main.php`  and `common/config/main-local.php`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in this component `common\components\VerificationNavigateur`.

You are accessing `Yii::$app->request->userAgent` in its `init()` method. This property is only available in `yii\web\Request`.
In your app the component `common\components\VerificationNavigateur` is bootstrapped even for your console app. But in that case the property `Yii::$app->request` contains instance of `yii\console\Request` that doesn't have property `userAgent`.

If you don't need that component in your console app you should remove it in your console config. If you need that component in console app you should modify its `init()` method to check if the `Yii::$app->request` is instance of `yii\web\Request` before accessing `userAgent` property for example like this:

```php
if (\Yii::$app->request instanceof \yii\web\Request) {
    // ... do something with Yii::$app->request->userAgent
}
```

In case of `php vendor/bin/yii` your app config is not used. That's why that component is not bootstrapped and you don't encounter that error. But, because the config is not loaded, there is no configuration for `db` component and migration is not working.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. And yes it was indeed the component ``common\components\VerificationNavigateur``that was causing problems. I forgot to mention that all of this happened after I've pulled the code from a colleague. Now it works fine !